# Extracting a list of installed Ubuntu packages to recreate server

Tags: package-management

Is there a way of extracting a list of currently installed packages in a Debian / Ubuntu system as a script that can automatically recreate it?

Seems like this should be fairly straightforward, but is there a standard command or tool for this?

Comment: Would it be a duplicate of this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages (the answer details on how to get the list, and how to get them re-installed in a new system). Note: This is just the packages not including any fine-tuning or server configuration.

Comment: That seems to be more do it yourself. I was really hoping that there was a tool to do it for me :-)